# Setting maximum CPU usage per process in Windows

Tags: windows-7, process, cpu-usage

Is there a way to set the maximum CPU usage for a process in Windows 7?

Comment: Do you mean a maximum number of CPU seconds or a maximum CPU%? If you mean maximum seconds, you can run it inside of a job object.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @Gabe this is working from Windows 8 upwards? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448384(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could check out "CPU rate limits in Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7" - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff384148%28WS.10%29.aspx

But be aware of the warning in http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2010/02/15/put-the-brakes-on-your-application-pools-cpu-rate-limits-in-windows-7.aspx. It says:
*Now here comes the drawback. The CPU Rate Limit feature has a bug. The kernel is holding on to a handle to the quota object and never lets go of it. This means once you set the CPU rate limit to a particular percentage you can't change this percentage without rebooting the machine. We are working on fixing it - not sure when we'll have a fix though.*  I have no idea if this bug is fixed.

Answer (score -11):

Open Task Manager. Right click on the process you want more CPU usage and select the Priority level you want.