# Python Multiprocessing Program doesn't fully utilise CPU resources on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, cpu-usage

I have a Python program on Windows which has a PyQt based user interface and uses multiprocessing to process a video stream in the background. The program runs fine if I launch it while no other programs are being run i.e. it launches multiple processes which use 100% of all available CPU resources on all cores.

But, if I launch some other application and then run the same Python program, it fails to use all the available CPU resources even if the CPU resources being used by other program is very minimal. Moreover, this reduced usage of CPU remains there even if I close all other applications later on.

I think somehow the OS is restricting the amount of CPU allocated to my program's processes if there are other programs running as well.

Comment: If what you saying is true, running multiple `python -c 'while True: pass'` processes should take one core of cpu, is that happening?

Comment: not sure what you meant by  python -c 'while True: pass'
Is this a command? While app is running its using 8 cores as shown by task manager.

Comment: `-c` will execute the content of it's argument, is a command. if you execute it would take 100% of one cpu. _I think somehow the OS is restricting the amount of CPU allocated to my program's processes if there are other programs running as well._ I never heard of this, I guess it's not the OS

Comment: _I think somehow the OS is restricting the amount of CPU allocated to my program's processes if there are other programs running as well._ Write a simple python program that take 100% cpu on all cores, and execute it to test your hypothesis

Comment: I tried running python program that took 100% cpu. My hypothesis was true. After I ran heavy application and quit them. Python program stopped taking 100% CPU. It was reduced to 50%

Comment: is it possible that we before we start a process, we can somehow manually use available CPU? @geckos

Comment: There should be a configuration for this so, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4326316/652528